# Python os.system "start" command not found while running through cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cygwin

I have python installed in C:\Python27. Also, I have cygwin installed with Python package. In cygwin64 terminal when I do "which python" it gives /usr/bin/python.

Now from command prompt when I run a simple python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

import os
os.system("start notepad.exe")
```

Notepad starts running.

But from Cygwin64 terminal when I do python run.py it throws an error: **"sh: start: command not found"**

What might be the reason? I have made the python script executable by chmod +x run.py through cygwin terminal. But that did not help.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Python question but Cygwin-related. Cygwin doesn't itself have the `start` command. That's a buitlin of `cmd.exe` if I recall correctly.

When you're in Cygwin, you're basically in a Unix environment. That means that

```
os.system("notepad.exe")
```

should be enough. The pre-requisite is that your `PATH` environment is set up correctly and includes the Windows directory where `notepad.exe` resides; for example `/c/windows` or `/c/winnt`.

You can do a dry-run of all this by just starting your Cygwin window (with a Bash process) and typing `notepad.exe`. If it starts, you're OK. Similarly when in Bash, if you type `start notepad.exe` then (again) the shell will say: `start: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not type Start.

This can be done in the following way.

import os
os.system("Notepad.exe")